# How to exclude derivation of Show from HPC's code-coverage?

Tags: haskell, testing, automated-tests, code-coverage, quickcheck

I have type that derives `Show`.
It's useful for development & required for testing, but not necessary for my application's logic, so it does not require any testing.

I want to make HPC aware of that to get 100% coverage for my tests. Is there any way to exclude it?
A setting? a pragma? a test to trick it?

I tried `seq`ing `show` but it didn't work at first (later it did and solved the issue, and I posted an answer, see it).

I also tried extending with `CPP` to use a macro condition that will exclude the `Show` just when testing, but `quickCheckAll` was not fond of that and I didn't even get through compilation (which is actually understandable in case of test-failure).

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question but here is an example of excluding code that you know will never be used: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_program_coverage#Example

Answer (score 1):

I eventually `seq`ed all `Show` has to offer so GHC will see that I've been there, and acknowledge I've covered it.
The following covers it on my type:

```
prop_fieldShow :: (Show i, Show a) => Field i a -> Bool
prop_fieldShow field = showList [field] `seq` showsPrec 0 field `seq` show field `seq` True
```

Comment: Did you try just covering `showList`? `showList` alone seems to also cover `show` and `showsPrec`. I got HPC to tick the `Show` box using something like `\f g -> (f /= g) ==> (show [f] /= show [g])`.